# Where and how exactly admin user is created?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I want to find part of code where admin user is created. 
I tried to grep files but didn't find anything.
Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done in the `addUserRights` method in `DMLRecordFactory` in `ybootstrap.jar` in `hybris/bin/platform/bootstrap/bin`

Answer (score 0):

in :

```
/platform/projet.properties

hmc.default.login=admin
hmc.default.password=nimda
```

Comment: This does not answer the question since these configuration do not participate in the admin creation. Try to connect to the hac with the modified values and you'll see that it won't work...